# How to retrieve filtered value from a stream and use it

Tags: java-8

I'm new to Java 8:
I have to convert this piece of java 6 code to java 8 version:

```
List<String> unvalidnumbers = new ArrayList<>();
StringBuilder content = new StringBuilder();
String str = "current_user"
for (Iterator<String> it = numbers.iterator(); it.hasNext();) {
        String number = it.next();
        try {
            PersIdentifier persIdentifier = this.getPersIdentifierByNumber(number);
            if (persIdentifier != null) {
                content.append(number).append(";").append(str);
                if (StringUtils.equals(persIdentifier.getType(), "R")) {
                    content.append(";X");
                }
                if (it.hasNext()) {
                    content.append("\r\n");
                }
            }
        } catch (BusException e) {
            LOGGER.warn("Pers not found", e);
            unvalidnumbers.add(number);
        }
    }
```

So i wrote this:

```
        numbers.stream().filter((String number) -> {
        try {
            return this.getPersIdentifierByNumber(number) != null;
        } catch (BusinessException e1) {
            LOGGER.warn("Pers not found", e1);
            return false;
        }
    }).forEach(number -> contentConstruction.append(number).append(";").append(str));
```

I know it's missing this part:

```
if (StringUtils.equals(persIdentifier.getType(), "R")) {
                    content.append(";X");
                }
if (it.hasNext()) {
                content.append("\r\n");
            }
```

But i didn't found  way to retrieve the corresponding persIdentifier object.
Any idea please

Comment: “retrieve a value from a stream” is the wrong mindset. A stream encapsulates an operation which will evaluate to a result. Find a way to formulate the operating such that it will produce the desired result. Hints: you probably want to `map` the `String` instances of the misleadingly named `numbers` to a compound string and then `collect` these elements into a `String` by `joining` them…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use a more functional approach if you use Java 8.
Instead of a `forEach`, favor `collect()`.  Here `Collectors.joining()` looks suitable.
Not tested but you should have an overall idea :

```
String result =
    numbers.stream()
           .map(number -> new SimpleEntry<String, PersIdentifier>(number, this.getPersIdentifierByNumber(number) )
           .filter(entry -> entry.getValue() != null)
           .map(entry ->{
                final String base = entry.getKey() + ";" + str;
                return "R".equals(entry.getValue().getType()) ? base + ";X" : base;
           })
           .collect(joining("\r\n")); // Or not OS dependent : System.lineSeparator()
```